# go to the supermarket/shops

Tags: definite-article

I'm confused by the use of the definite article in this sentence whether it's used in a generic sense or both
the listener/reader knows exactly what we're referring to? Or there is only one restaurant and shop in the vinicity?

- I'm going to go to the supermarket after work. Here, does "the" refer to a generic idea of restaurant? Any restaurant.
- I need to go to the shops - I've got no food in the house. Here, does "the" also refer to a generic idea  of shops? Any shos
- There is no milk. I'll buy some when I go to the shops. (Any shops)

Comment: This has ben discussed many  times, for example [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344866/we-met-in-a-the-supermarket). _The supermarket/bank/hairdresser etc._ can mean either 'a specific one that we both know' OR 'an unspecified one local to me'.

Comment: There was a similar question about this recently...  Also please fix your first example (restaraunt/supermarket)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The question about the English articles. A/an or The?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246721/the-question-about-the-english-articles-a-an-or-the) Also [to a shop vs to the shop](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139747/to-a-shop-vs-to-the-shop) and this OP's own [Definite article for a particular purpose](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344857/definite-article-for-a-particular-purpose), among others.

Comment: [*People say "I'm going to the shop" because they have a specific shop in mind, but they don't need to specify because it is either obvious (perhaps there is a shop at the corner of the street that is the default choice due to its convenience) or because **it doesn't matter.***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/246741/126)

Comment: "the" is specific; "a" is generic. How many times must one say that?

Comment: @KateBunting What's the meaning of "specific" in the use of "the". Perhaps I'm unclear with this term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For instance, I live near five or six shops or such other places that have more than one. I'm going to one of them, I know which shop I am going to but the person I am talking to does not know it. Do I still useb"the?" A conversation might go:
**A**: *Where are you going?*
**Me**: *I'm going to the shops.*

Comment: @JamesK Thanks James K. That helps me a great deal.

Comment: Nyambek - SWMcdonnell has said the same thing in an answer. I meant 'one particular supermarket'.

Comment: @KateBunting *My car was in the street, but now it's in the garage*. Here as a reader, I don't know which street/garage the speaker is referring to. Could you explain the use of "the" here?

Comment: Assuming that the speaker is at home, I would understand them to mean "the street outside my house" and "my own garage".

Comment: @KateBunting Is "garage" common place here? So "the" doesn't refer to a specific noun?

Comment: "Garage" can mean either a place where motor vehicles are repaired, or a building to keep a private car in. I assumed that your sentence referred to the second meaning. If the car is being repaired, _in the garage_ would mean 'an unspecified garage, probably the one I normally use'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150268/discussion-between-nyambek-and-kate-bunting).

Answer (score 0):

**the supermarket** refers either to a generic supermarket or one that we both understand to be the one you normally go to.

In American English, you would say **store** instead of **shops**:

> I need to go to the **store**.
>
> We're out of milk. I'll get some when I go to the **store**.

Comment: the supermarket is the one near you OR one we both know. I would say specific rather than generic for "the". I'm going to the supermarket [in my town, down the street, in the next town].

Comment: @Lambie For instance, I live near five or six shops or such other places that have more than one, *bank*, *petrol station*, etc. I'm going to one of them, I know which shop I am going to but the person I am talking to does not know it. Do I still useb"the?" A conversation might go:
**A**: *Where are you going?*
**Me**: *I'm going to the shops/the bank/the petrol station.*

Comment: It doesn't matter what you live near. These are basically idiomatic usages. Just learn them. If you say "I'm going to the supermarket" it means something like any one of the supermarkets near you. As opposed to, say, I'm off to the mechanic's.